# Udev rules from RHEL 7

Tags: linux, oracle11g, udev

There are changes in the Udev rules from RHEL 7, [this](http://houseofbrick.com/udev-rules/) has wonderful explanation,

I am looking for some official document on this, Please  help

form http://houseofbrick.com/udev-rules/

> As you might have gathered, udev rules are a fundamental piece of
>   making Linux work. So, this really makes me wonder why such a
>   fundamental piece of the Linux OS was changed, in what is a fairly
>   dramatic way, in the next release of Redhat Linux, RHEL 7.
>   Specifically, the location of the scsi_id program has changed, and the
>   parameter used in the command have changed. The NAME option can no
>   longer be used for disk devices, it only works for network devices. So
>   the equivalent of the udev rule above, in RHEL 7 would be this:

Comment: Maybe Oftopic. You do not have to use OracleASM. You can also assign persistent device names to disks in `/etc/multipathd.conf`

Comment: I am not using oracle asm lib my udev rule in RHEL 7.1 which is working fine is "SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="powerai", SYMLINK+="DG-DISK1", OWNER="grid", GROUP="oinstall", MODE="0660""

Comment: We are using EMC Powerpath for multi path.